# tcpdump and wireshark: Show timestamp

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

1. I run `tcpdump` on a remote host.
2. I copy the dump to my linux workstation.
3. I look at it with wireshark

The customer tells: Please look at the traffic at 8 o'clock.

... I found no way to filter the traffic to a time range.

I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [display filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html) to filter on time range.
For example:
(frame.time >= "Mar 18, 2015 20:38:04.705104000") && (frame.time <= "Mar 18, 2015 20:38:06.415883000")

Useful link:
[WiresharK Wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters)

Comment: Thank you very much! ISO date formats are supported, too: `frame.time > "2015-09-03 20:38:04"`

Answer (score 1):

to view the time of the capture, go to "View" -> "Time display format" and choose "Date and time of day"